# How to write tests for multiple arrays of integers?

Tags: python

new to Python, I would like to learn coding with Python by testing the code I write using either pytest or unittest. In that regard I'm wondering how to test assertions about multiple arrays as inputs:

I have a function `extractDifferentNumber` which aims to return a integer doesn't belong to the rest of the sequence of integers:

```
def extractDifferentNumber(df):
    df_set = set(df)
    for each in df_set:
        if df.count(each) == 1:
            return each
```

which extracts that different number out of a sequence of numbers:

```
# print(extractDifferentNumber([10,11,10,10,10,10,10])) 11
# print(extractDifferentNumber([20,11,20,20,20]))  11
# print(extractDifferentNumber([1,1,1,1,2])) 2
```

Now I would like to use unittest to verify that my functions returns the expected outcome:

```
class SingleDifferentNumberTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test for `myfunction.py`"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.input = [10,11,10,10,10,10,10]
        self.expected = [11]

    def test_is_different(self):
        """Is a number different then the others"""
        self.assertTrue(extractDifferentNumber())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In that regard, I have two questions:

How can I include multiple arrays / testcases as `self.input` and `self.expected` and how can I raise the appropriate assertion like  `self.assertTrue` for instance using unittest?

Comment: how about [1,2,3]?

Comment: @Copperfield:  c’mon, man, the question is about how to write unit tests.  Not about how to handle corner cases with a particular algorithm.  Mamba definitely provided us an MVCE.

Comment: @2ps well, you already handle that part, so why not consider corner cases too, those are the ones that help you make better algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [add multiple methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) each which start with the letters `test`:

> A testcase is created by subclassing `unittest.TestCase`. The three
>   individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the
>   letters `test`. This naming convention informs the test runner about
>   which methods represent tests.
>
> The crux of each test is a call to `assertEqual()` to check for an
>   expected result; `assertTrue()` or `assertFalse()` to verify a condition;
>   or `assertRaises()` to verify that a specific exception gets raised.
>   These methods are used instead of the `assert` statement so the test
>   runner can accumulate all test results and produce a report.

---

```
class SingleDifferentNumberTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test for `myfunction.py`"""

    def test_array_1(self):
        """Is a number different then the others"""
        self.assertEqual(extractDifferentNumber([10,11,10,10,10,10,10]), 11)

    def test_array_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(extractDifferentNumber([20,11,20,20,20]), 11)

    def test_array_3(self):
        self.assertEqual(extractDifferentNumber([1,1,1,1,2]), 2)
```